# EF Core: How to cascade delete when DB-first FK is the wrong way around?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, cascade

Consider this (admittedly rather confused) entity model of a legacy database:

[image]

As you can see it models `Blog`s that have a collection of `Entry`s which point to a blog `Post` each. The tips of the arrows point to the principal/parent of the relationship. At least this is the way EF core sees it based on where the foreign keys are stored.

Unfortunately the FK between `Entry` and `Post` is the wrong way around, because a `Post` is actually a child of an `Entry`; i.e. when I delete an `Entry` from a `Blog` then the associated `Post` should be deleted as well.

As I'm unable to change the schema of the legacy database, I'm wondering how I can convice EF to cascade-delete `Post`s although it doesn't consider them to be children of `Entry`s.

I tried specifiying the `DeleteBehavior` explicitely to no avail:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Post)
    .WithOne(p => p.Entry)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I also tried making the navigation property `Post.Entry` required to indicate that a `Post` cannot live without its `Entry`, but that didn't help either:

```
public class Post {
    // ...
    [Required]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Entry.Post))]
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently checking if [owned entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) could help, but I'm sceptical.

I guess what I need is a way to explicitely state the parent/principal of an entity relationship. Something like [`SetPrincipalEntityType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencereferencebuilder.setprincipalentitytype).

Of course I could always manually delete the `Post`, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Any ideas anyone?

#### Working example

I created a [test project](https://github.com/bert2/ef-vs-garbage-db) with integration tests that you can use to reproduce the issue:

```bsh
> git clone https://github.com/bert2/ef-vs-garbage-db.git
> cd .\ef-vs-garbage-db\
> dotnet test
```

The test [DeletesTextWhenDeletingReview](https://github.com/bert2/ef-vs-garbage-db/blob/4b8e205d3ee21976e6b859473bc7ff9000345ab6/Tests/BloggingContextTests.cs#L117) will fail.

Comment: Delete it manually. Lying EF won't help. First, the entity with FK cannot be a principal. Second, EF relies on database performing cascade delete. Simply do it manually, there is no other way.

Comment: @IvanStoev There actually was a way to do this. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14658

Comment: Well, this is still manual deletion (custom client side code with additional load requirements), hence I won't call it "cascade delete".

Comment: @IvanStoev well that's true. But at least the client code doesn't have to do the delete, because the context does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on the EF Core GitHub page. The idea of the [solution posted there](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14658#issuecomment-462496888) is to find the orphaned entities in an override of `SaveChanges()` and delete them manually:

```
public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
{
    // Note that this is internal code to force cascade deletes to happen.
    // It may stop working in any future release.
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    this.GetService<IStateManager>().GetEntriesToSave();

    try
    {
        ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker
            .Entries<CritiqueText>()
            .Where(e => Entry(e.Entity.Review).State == EntityState.Deleted))
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
}
```

I took this and build an attribute based solution from this that you can find in the [test project repo](https://github.com/bert2/ef-vs-garbage-db/blob/master/GarbageDb/BloggingContext.cs).